# How do I override the str function without raising a UnicodeEncodeError?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I am puzzled that defining `__str__` for a class seems to have no effect on using the `str` function on a class instance. For example, I read in the Django documentation that:

> The `print` statement and the `str` built-in call `__str__()` to determine the human-readable representation of an object.

But that doesn't appear to be true. Here's an example from a module where `text` is always assumed to be unicode:

```
import six

class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, text):
        self._text = text

    def __str__(self):
        if six.PY3:
            return str(self._text)
        else:
            return unicode(self._text)

    def __unicode__(self):
        if six.PY3:
            return str(self._text)
        else:
            return unicode(self._text)
```

In Python 2, it gives the following behavior:

```
>>> a=Test(u'café')
>>> print a.__str__()
café
>>> print a # same error with str(a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-202e444820fd> in <module>()
----> 1 str(a)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to overload the `str` function?

Comment: `print a.__str__()` will produce `café`, **not** `'café'`.

Comment: You caught me out cutting and pasting the wrong line. Thanks for your answer below, which I'm pretty sure is correct. I'll accept it when I've done a few more checks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Python 2, you are returning the wrong type from the `__str__` method. You are returning `unicode`, while you **must** return `str`:

```
def __str__(self):
    if six.PY3:
        return str(self._text)
    else:
        return self._text.encode('utf8')
```

Because `self._text` is not already of type `str`, you'll need to encode it. Because you returned Unicode instead, Python is forced to encode it first, but the default ASCII encoding can't handle the non-ASCII `é` character.

Printing the object results in the right output only because my terminal is configured to handle UTF-8:

```
>>> a = Test(u'café')
>>> str(a)
'caf\xc3\xa9'
>>> print a
café
>>> unicode(a)
u'caf\xe9'
```

Note that there is *no `__unicode__` method* in Python 3; your `if six.PY3` in that method is entirely redundant. The following would work too:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self._text = text

    def __str__(self):
        if six.PY3:
            return self._text
        else:
            return self._text.encode('utf8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self._text
```

However, if you are using the `six` library, you'd be far better of using the [`@six.python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.python_2_unicode_compatible), and only define a Python 3 version for the `__str__` method:

```
@six.python_2_unicode_compatible
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self._text = text

    def __str__(self):
        return self._text
```

where it is assumed `text` is always Unicode. If you are working with Django, then you can get the same decorator from the [`django.utils.encoding` module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.encoding).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your comments have helped me to fix my own code, which is more complicated than the example. However, it still seems to be true that `a.__str__()` and `str(a)` are not after all equivalent. This would appear to me to be a case where Python 2 is inconsistent, automatically encoding the first in the print statement but not the second. I can see, however, that it is dangerous to let Python guess what you really meant.

Comment: @RayOsborn: No, `str` and `a.__str__()` are not *equivalent*. `str` is a type, `object.__str__()` is a hook method used by `str` to help convert other objects to the type. You broke the contract of the `object.__str__()` hook method, which is that it **must** return a `str` type value, otherwise the conversion was a failure; the `str` type can't just return a `unicode` type object instead.

Comment: @RayOsborn: that Python 2 also tries to make `unicode` objects containing only ASCII codepoints exchangeable with `str` objects with the same contents may have made this all a little more complicated, but the [reference documentation for `object.__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) does state the requirement that a string object must be returned.

Comment: Thanks. Your comments have been very helpful.